# commons io 403 for URL but httpclient is ok

Tags: java, http, httpclient, http-status-code-403, apache-commons-io

commons io code :

```
String resultURL = String.format(GOOGLE_RECOGNIZER_URL, URLEncoder.encode("hello", "UTF-8"), "en-US");
URI uri = new URI(resultURL);
byte[] resultIO = IOUtils.toByteArray(uri);
```

I got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://translate.google.cn/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=hello&tl=en-US&total=1&idx=0&textlen=3
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:654)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:635)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:617)
    at com.renren.intl.soundsns.simsimi.speech.ttsclient.impl.GoogleTTSClient.main(GoogleTTSClient.java:70)
```

but when I use httpclient, the result is ok.

```
String resultURL = String.format(GOOGLE_RECOGNIZER_URL, URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8"), "en-US");

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

GetMethod g = new GetMethod(resultURL);

client.executeMethod(g);

byte[] resultByte = g.getResponseBody();
```

How this happened?

thanks in advance :)

maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Have you tried using WireShark or something similar to look at the difference in requests? I suspect HttpClient sets a different User-Agent or something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jon Skeet is right!

For me in case of java.net.URL JVM pass next headers:

```
User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_10
Host: translate.google.cn
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
```

In case of Apache HttpClient:

```
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: translate.google.cn
```

And if you change, the user agent for java.net.URL:

```
System.setProperty("http.agent", "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1");
```

request is successful, without HTTP 403.

Looks like you get 403 error if your user-agent start with: `Java`. Any user agent with pattern `Java.*` throws 403 error. But if you use this pattern `.+Java.*` all is ok.

Comment: if I want to down files which one is better? @Taky

Comment: @Felix I would build the abstraction layer with the convenient for my application interface to work with http(e.g. byte[] MyApplicationHttClient#getBinaData(String url);). And at first start to use java.net.URL. If it is not enough for me I would change implementation to HttpClient only in one place.

Comment: Solved the same error for me. But I would like to know what is the exact reason for sending 403 in case Java is used in the user-agent