# How can I solve error 403 while using apache commons io?

Tags: java, json, gson, http-status-code-403, apache-commons-io

I'm trying to get json code from an url with gson library and I'm using apache commons io for get the url. But the problem is that when I execute te code, the exit returns a 403 error.
How can I solve this problem?
Here is the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class gsonexample {

    public gsonexample() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        String url = "http://freemusicarchive.org/api/get/albums.json?api_key=60BLHNQCAOUFPIBZ&limit=5";
        String json = IOUtils.toString(new URL(url));
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        // The JsonElement is the root node. It can be an object, array, null or
        // java primitive.
        JsonElement element = parser.parse(json);
        // use the isxxx methods to find out the type of jsonelement. In our
        // example we know that the root object is the Albums object and
        // contains an array of dataset objects
        if (element.isJsonObject()) {
            JsonObject albums = element.getAsJsonObject();
            System.out.println(albums.get("title").getAsString());
            JsonArray datasets = albums.getAsJsonArray("dataset");
            for (int i = 0; i < datasets.size(); i++) {
                JsonObject dataset = datasets.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                System.out.println(dataset.get("album_title").getAsString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the exit:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://freemusicarchive.org/api/get/albums.json?api_key=60BLHNQCAOUFPIBZ&limit=5
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:1153)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:1140)
    at gestor.de.colecciones.gsonexample.<init>(gsonexample.java:24)
    at gestor.de.colecciones.main.main(main.java:62)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application gestor.de.colecciones.main
Java Result: 1
```

gsonexample.java:24 is String json = IOUtils.toString(new URL(url));

Comment: 403 means you need authorization. The URL you are trying to call forbids you in this case.

Comment: I am not getting HTTP ERROR 403 for this URL
http://freemusicarchive.org/api/get/albums.json?api_key=60BLHNQCAOUFPIBZ&limit=5
It works fine at my end. Can you paste headers of your request here?

Comment: But you enter by a web explorer or by the code? By web explorer I don't have problems to see the json code.
The log is in the explanation. I can't see the headers (or I don't know how...).

Comment: use curl in verbose mode, play with the parameters. If you don't get a 403 then you can set up your request the same way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [commons io 403 for URL but httpclient is ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996140/commons-io-403-for-url-but-httpclient-is-ok)

Comment: it's a user agent problem, see the question in the comment above. Adding `System.setProperty("http.agent", "curl/7.51.0");` before calling `IOUtils` works.

Comment: @tima your code works perfectly. But can you give me a little explanation of setProperty, please? I saw different arguments for this function.

Comment: @tima, with the url I tested it works, but with this url: https://www.giantbomb.com/api/search/?api_key=mypersonalapikey&query=%22Devil%20May%20Cry%22&format=json isn't working (403). If I try the new url in Firefox returns also a json well formed. I don't know what's happening.

Comment: @DanielRuiz It seems like the owner of the website allows browsers and `curl` to access the URL but is not allowing some of the user agents like java's user agent. `System.setProperty` sets a JVM property so when you run the program it will overwrite the default value. In this case, I used `curl/7.51.0` because I used `curl` to test the URL and it worked, so I used the same user agent in the java program and it also worked. It doesn't have to be `curl/7.51.0`, I tried with random characters and it still worked. The owner of the website / API controls what user agent can access it.

Comment: In this moment I don't have an error 403. I think I will create a new question in stackoverflow related with setProperty, because the initial problem was solved and need more space for explain the new problem. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same problem and found your question.

One of the comments says to use

```
System.setProperty("http.agent", "curl/7.51.0").
```

So I did, and still got the same error. So I copied and pasted the url in your code (which was exactly the same as mine) into my browser address bar and pressed ENTER. The response was:

```
{"title":"Free Music Archive - Albums","message":"","errors":["invalid or disabled api_key"],"http_status":403,"dataset":[]}.
```

Hope this helps. Suggest we both study freemusicarchive.com to find a valid and/or not disabled key.

Good luck and happy computing.